# "Augur" : Is it an "Oracle" or "data-source" ? which one?

Tags: oracles, augur

If we define following three entities (as defined [HERE](https://blog.oraclize.it/understanding-oracles-99055c9c9f7b)):

```
(1) data-source

(2) query

(3) the oracle/oracle network
```

Then, [as this article says](https://blog.oraclize.it/understanding-oracles-99055c9c9f7b), is "**Augur**" a **data-source** ? Or it is an "**Oracle**" ?

Comment: A data-source, I'd say

Answer (score 2):

The premise of this question is Oraclize's definition which doesn't really match how people have historically used the term. On their definition Augur would be a data source, and you don't need an oracle.

What people normally mean by "oracle" is more like "a black box that gives you information somehow", in which case Augur is an oracle and a data source.

Their definition of the "query" is even further from normal English: To non-oraclize humans a query is the content of the request, not the "formula". If it was a formula, I suppose Augur's query is the human language you ask the question in. But to the rest of us, a query is the content of the question, ie the thing you're trying to find out. This sometimes encompasses a particular way of structuring that thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is really fair to describe Augur as only one of the 3 items. Just like Oraclize, I think Augur has all 3 aspects in their "decentralized oracle".

In Augur you have:

- `data-source`: Users who use Augur, report the outcome of events, and participate in the prediction markets
- `query`: The market created for a particular event
- `the oracle/oracle network`: The Augur smart contract which manages the market life-cycle and disputes with outcomes